# Recursively merge like indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has like indexes that I am trying to merge together. For some reason I can't wrap my head around it.

### **Original Array**

```
$seperateArray = json_decode('[
{ "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "Harold" },
{ "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "Arthur" },
{ "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "Tom" },
{ "tier1": "Group2", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "Beth" },
{ "tier1": "Group3", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "Peter" }]', true);
```

### Turn it into:

```
{
    "Group1": {
        "Blue": {
            "Round": [
                "Harold",
                "Arthur",
                "Tom"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Group2": {
        "Blue": {
            "Round": [
                "Peter"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I am at so far but I don't know if I'm moving in the right direction.

```
$newCombined = array();

//this each statement will show every tier 1-4 array object
foreach($seperateArray as $s) {

    if(!array_key_exists($s['tier1'], $newCombined) $newCombined[$s['tier1']] = array();
    if(!array_key_exists($newCombined[$s['tier1']][$s['tier2']], $newCombined[$s['tier1']])) $newCombined[$s['tier1']][$s['tier2']] = array();
    //.. and so on

}
```

Comment: Is there a chance it can have another dimension?

Comment: @pr1nc3 There will only be the indexes tier1-4 but the values could be quite different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only `tier4` can produce an array, then it is a simple matter of looping and assigning (if you're ok with silencing notices):

```
$array = json_decode('...', true);
$new = [];

foreach ($array as $e)
    @$new[$e['tier1']][$e['tier2']][$e['tier3']][] = $e['tier4'];

echo json_encode($new, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); # to print what you asked for
```

To make the assignment a little less cryptic:

```
foreach ($array as $e) {
    list($t1, $t2, $t3, $t4) = array_values($e);
    @$new[$t1][$t2][$t3][] = $t4;
}
```

---

To go back from `$new` to the original array:

```
$original = [];

foreach (array_keys($new) as $t1)
    foreach (array_keys($new[$t1]) as $t2)
        foreach (array_keys($new[$t1][$t2]) as $t3)
            foreach ($new[$t1][$t2][$t3] as $t4)
                $original[] = [
                    'tier1' => $t1,
                    'tier2' => $t2,
                    'tier3' => $t3,
                    'tier4' => $t4,
                ];

echo json_encode($original, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you sidyll! Totally makes sense now. Didn't think about surpressing notices

Comment: Thanks @bryan , happy to help. Suppressing notices generally raises a discussion with religious arguments...but if you're ok with it it really simplifies things in this case. I'd say it's one of the very few legitimate uses of `@`. If you don't want to use, you'd have to check for the existence of every key and then create it if necessary. Otherwise, let PHP create them automatically (as many languages do) and just ignore notices that it would generate in this case only with the `@`. In my opinion, very handy.

Comment: Yup, this is just setting up some data and not continually used in production so this is a perfect use case for me. I appreciate the time.

Comment: This is super random, but any idea on how you could go backwards from the end array to the beginning array? @sidyll

Comment: @bryan I updated the answer to include a suggestion on solving that :)

Answer (score 1):

Sidyll's answer is perfect but as I was working on my own solution, I'll post it too:

```
$input = json_decode('[
  { "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "Harold" },
  { "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "Arthur" },
  { "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "Tom" },
  { "tier1": "Group2", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "Beth" },
  { "tier1": "Group3", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "Peter" }]', true);

$output = [];

foreach($input as $row) {
  $recursion = &$output;
  foreach($row as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'tier4' && !isset($recursion[$value])) {
      $recursion[$value] = [];
    }
    if ($key == 'tier4') {
      $recursion[] = $value;
    } else {
      $recursion = &$recursion[$value];
    }
  }
}

var_dump($output);
```

> array(3) { ["Group1"]=> array(1) { ["Blue"]=> array(1) { ["Round"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "Harold" [1]=> string(6) "Arthur" [2]=> string(3) "Tom" } } } ["Group2"]=> array(1) { ["Blue"]=> array(1) { ["Round"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "Beth" } } } ["Group3"]=> array(1) { ["Blue"]=> array(1) { ["Round"]=> &array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Peter" } } } }

Not particularly proud of it, but it works.

Comment: This is a very nice strategy! Thanks for posting it too.

Comment: Thank you, @sidyll :) TBH, It feels kinda dirty after seeing your approach.

Comment: Not dirty at all, it's a clever approach and could be used in more situations than mine since it traverses data in a flexible way.