# Recursively cycle every path of an array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have the following(json) object:

```
$obj = json_decode('{
    "Group1": {
        "Blue": {
            "Round": [
                "Harold",
                "Arthur",
                "Tom"
            ]
        },
        "Green": {
            "Round": [
                "Harold"
            ],
            "Circle": [
                "Todd",
                "Mike"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Group2": {
        "Blue": {
            "Round": [
                "Peter"
            ]
        }
    }
}', true);
```

I'm trying to figure out how to recursively travel through it so I can see all the different paths that is in the array.

It could be 4 separate echo's or a 4 line string. The `>` could be replaced with anything or nothing at all. If each line was echo'd separately or pushed to an array that would probably give the most flexibility.

```
Group1 - Blue - Round - (Harold, Arthur, Tom)
Group1 - Green - Round - (Harold)
Group1 - Green - Circle - (Todd, Mike)
Group2 - Blue - Round - (Peter)
```

I can't wrap my head around it so any help would be appreciated.

I'm thinking I can somehow cycle through each like:

```
foreach($obj as $index => $value)
{
   // and then somehow do this until you reach an array?
}
```

Comment: You need to go through each member? Maybe you want something like `array_walk`

Comment: Yea to find each path. Hmm, not sure how that works with a deep array but I'll try and look into it

Comment: Is your object always on the format of `Group > Color > Shapes > Names` ? Or there could be additional categories or something?

Comment: I'd know how many levels deep (in this case 4 but it could be 2,8, etc) and the last one is always an array, but unfortunately the names could be different. @Erwin

Comment: Please post the exact output structure that you want.  Do you actually want a 4-line string?  Or do you want an 1-dim array with four elements?  Do you want us to echo it from the recursive function?  Do you want the result to be returned as a set of concatenated strings?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. If each line (or "path") was echo'd separately or pushed to an array that would probably give the most flexibility. @mickmackusa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested only on the given sample. But this should work if array levels are increased. I mainly use `RecursiveIteratorIterator` class functions

```
// Initialize RecursiveIteratorIterator
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($obj), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$paths = array(); // Paths storage
foreach ($iterator as $k => $v) { // Loop thru each iterator

    if (!$iterator->hasChildren()) { // Check if iterator hasChildren is false
        $innermost = $iterator->getSubIterator($iterator->getDepth()); // Get innermost child which is the array
        for ($p = array(), $i = 0, $z = $iterator->getDepth(); $i <= $z; $i++) { // Loop and push each path to the innermost array
            $p[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
        }
        array_pop($p); // Remove key
        $innermost = (array)$innermost; // Cast innermost to array
        $p[] = '(' . implode(', ', $innermost) . ')'; // push formatted innermost array to path
        $path = implode(' - ', $p); // implode the path
        $paths[] = $path; // store to list of paths array
    }

}

$paths = array_unique($paths); // remove exactly same paths

foreach ($paths as $value) {  // Loop and echo each path
    echo $value.'<br>';
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/915070

Answer (score 2):

This works for different depth of the array, check the [live demo](https://eval.in/915495).

```
while(count($array) != count($array, 1))    // stop when $array is one dimension
{
    $temp = [];
    foreach($array as $k => $v)
    {
        if(is_array($v))
        {
            if(count($v) != count($v, 1))  // check if reached the inner most array
            {
                foreach($v as $kk => $vv)
                {
                    $temp[$k . ' - ' . $kk] = $vv;
                }
            }
            else
                $temp[$k] = '(' . implode($v, ', ') . ')';
        }else
            $temp[$k] = $v;
    }
    $array = $temp;
}

foreach($array as $k => $v)
    echo $k . ' - ' . $v . "\n";
```

**Note：**

[traverse array from outer to inner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708304/6521116)
[traverse array from inner to outer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47666851/6521116)

Comment: Based on assumption this is more accurate.+1

Comment: @mickmackusa, I'm sorry for not instantly response to your comment. I've imporved my answer. Can you check it now. If it do, please remove the downvote. Thank you.

Comment: For someone downvote on my answer, I first apoligize for my prier former answer which is inadequate. But now I've imporved it, can you take off your downvote, for it works now.

Comment: Great stacking technique. I was going to go down this path to be different from the others.  Reversed and +1.

Answer (score 2):

I have created simple recursive function.For your example. Store previous key values in one variable and add all data according to previous key and create new array.(which contain all previous keys as index and last element as value)   . Try following code:

```
$obj = json_decode('{
    "Group1": {
        "Blue": {
            "Round": [
                "Harold",
                "Arthur",
                "Tom"
            ]
        },
        "Green": {
            "Round": [
                "Harold"
            ],
            "Circle": [
                "Todd",
                "Mike"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Group2": {
        "Blue": {
            "Round": [
                "Peter"
            ]
        }
    }
}', true);

function traverse_array($array,$key="",$prev="",&$final_op=array())
{
  if(is_array($array))
  {
    $prev .= $key." - ";
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      traverse_array($value,$key,$prev,$final_op);
    }
  }
  else
  {

    $prev =trim($prev," - ");            
    $final_op[$prev][]=$array;
  }
  return $final_op;
}
$data = traverse_array($obj);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  echo $key." (".implode(",", $value).")";
  echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/kah84)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

i have created sample recursive program which u can tune

```
$obj = json_decode('{"Group1": {
        "Blue": {
            "Round": [
                "Harold",
                "Arthur",
                "Tom"
            ]
        },
        "Green": {
            "Round": [
                "Harold"
            ],
            "Circle": [
                "Todd",
                "Mike"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Group2": {
        "Blue": {
            "Round": [
                "Peter"
            ]
        }
    }
}');


recursive($obj);

function recursive($obj){

    if(is_array($obj)){

        foreach ($obj as $k => $v) {
            echo $v." ";
        }

        return;
    }

    foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
        echo $key. " =>";
        recursive($value);
    }

    echo "\n";

}
```

Following is sample output

```
Group1 =>Blue =>Round =>Harold Arthur Tom 
Green =>Round =>Harold Circle =>Todd Mike 
Group2 =>Blue =>Round =>Peter
```

Comment: Please deliver the expected result.

Comment: @mickmackusa im eagerly waiting for yours ;p, this answer wont handle arrays only objects, though close.

Comment: (I'm working on it -- while splitting my attention with my daughter.) @lawrence

Comment: This answer does not provide the expected result.  Please be discerning Upvote Pixies.  Upvoting inadequate answer ensures that they are left on the page to confuse future readers and waste their time.

Comment: I need to downvote this inadequate answer now. Since there are two correct answers, this answer is just noise and will not benefit future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I've boiled down my method to something VERY simple and easy to read.  See inline comments for explanations.  I have two versions: a 4-line echoing function and an array returning function.

*Note this method is very SPECIFICALLY built for this question because:

- The input array will ALWAYS have a depth of at least two levels AND

**Method #1 - echo strings from inside the function:** ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/444e9a160184cc7d3a0e8be93a64243bd4d60fec))

```
$array=json_decode('{
    "Group1": {
        "Blue": {
            "Round": {
                "One": [
                    "Lawrence",
                    "Anant",
                    "B."
                ],
                "Two": [
                    "Erwin"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Green": [
           "Bryan",
           "Mick"
        ]
    },
    "Group2": [
        "Peter",
        "Kris"
    ]
}', true);

function recurse($array,$path=''){
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        if(!is_array(current($v))){  // check type of the first sub-element's value
            echo ($path?"$path > ":''),"$k > (".implode(', ',$v).")\n";  // don't recurse, just implode the indexed elements
        }else{                                                           // recurse because at least 2 levels below
            recurse($v,($path?"$path > $k":$k));                         // build path appropriately
        }
    }
}
recurse($array);
```

Output:

```
Group1 > Blue > Round > One > (Lawrence, Anant, B.)
Group1 > Blue > Round > Two > (Erwin)
Group1 > Green > (Bryan, Mick)
Group2 > (Peter, Kris)
```

---

**Method #2 - return a 4-element array of paths:** ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/44333906d92cbeb7a780e3db4612fe955a9d2f72))

```
function recurse($array,$path='',&$result=[]){
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        if(!is_array(current($v))){  // check type of the first sub-element's value
            $result[]=($path?"$path > ":'')."$k > (".implode(', ',$v).')';  // don't recurse, just implode the indexed elements
        }else{  // recurse because at least 2 levels below
            recurse($v,($path?"$path > ":'').$k,$result);  // build path appropriately
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
var_export(recurse($array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Group1 > Blue > Round > One > (Lawrence, Anant, B.)',
  1 => 'Group1 > Blue > Round > Two > (Erwin)',
  2 => 'Group1 > Green > (Bryan, Mick)',
  3 => 'Group2 > (Peter, Kris)',
)
```

---

And one final update:

The best advice I can give would be to cut out this middle step and just convert [your raw/initial json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637510/recursively-merge-like-indexes) to your new desired output (no recursion/stacking required):

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7969992305fd75a2ff6f79ac610894bd99c0c733))

```
$seperateArray = json_decode('[
{ "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "One", "tier5": "Lawrence" },
{ "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "One", "tier5": "Anant" },
{ "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "One", "tier5": "B." },
{ "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Blue", "tier3": "Round", "tier4": "Two", "tier5": "Erwin" },
{ "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Green", "tier3": "Bryan" },
{ "tier1": "Group1", "tier2": "Green", "tier3": "Mick" },
{ "tier1": "Group2", "tier2": "Peter" },
{ "tier1": "Group2", "tier2": "Kris" }]',true);

foreach($seperateArray as $row){
    $last_val=current(array_splice($row,-1));  // extract last element, store as string
    $results[implode(' > ',$row)][]=$last_val;
}
foreach($results as $k=>$v){
    echo "$k > (",implode(', ',$v),")\n";
}
// same output as earlier methods
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take with a generator function:

```
function paths(array $a)
{
    // if first item is an array, recurse
    if (is_array(reset($a))) {
        foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
            foreach (paths($v) as $path) {
                // yield "key - subpath"
                yield sprintf('%s - %s', $k, $path);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // yield leaf
        yield sprintf('(%s)', implode(', ', $a));
    }
}

foreach (paths($obj) as $path) {
    printf("%s\n", $path);
}
```

Try it [online](https://3v4l.org/1atQk).

Comment: Sorry @Joe apparently late/refined answers are not acknowledged on this page.  My answer was just 24 hours late and despite the upvotes that I dealt to all of the other correct answers, there was no reciprocation.  StackOverflow is not always a place of justice.