# Delete some data from Array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to delete some data from an array in PHP. Here is the array:

```
array(4) {
    [0]=> array(1) { ["image"]=> string(20) "w85YrKChBGTZ9fQS.jpg" }
    [1]=> array(1) { ["image"]=> string(20) "3buahEs6rRWFdYez.jpg" }
    [2]=> array(1) { ["image"]=> string(20) "gYPtDrx3sFzkVENB.jpg" }
    [3]=> array(1) { ["image"]=> string(20) "JE3rodDvs6521cFm.jpg" }
}
```

Here is my method and where I am deleting:

```
public function deleteImage(){
    foreach (getCarImages() as $array){
        //var_dump($array).'<br>';
        $index = array_search('w85YrKChBGTZ9fQS.jpg',$array);
        if($index !== FALSE){
            var_dump($index).'<br>';
            unset($array[$index]);
        }else{
            echo '<br>else here';
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the result of `deleteImage()`

> string(5) "image"
>
> else
>
> > here
>
> else
>
> > here
>
> else
>
> > here

I am confused. How can I delete a nested array from the main array.

Comment: try `if($index)`. if item not found then `array_search` return empty.

Comment: please post your `getCarImages()` function.  What is `deleteImage()` actually going to do?  Is there a return value?  A file function? A database query?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to delete a whole subarray from array, then use [`array_flter`](http://php.net/array_filter) function:

```
public function deleteImage(){
    return array_filter(getCarImages(), function ($v) {
        return $v['image'] != 'w85YrKChBGTZ9fQS.jpg';
    });
}
```

**Update:** Anonymous function doesn't know about `$imageName` variable. You have to `use` it:

```
public function deleteImage($imageName = null) 
{ 
    $myarray = array_filter(
        getCarImages(), 
        function ($v) use ($imageName) { return $v['image'] != $imageName; }
    );
}
```

Comment: Its working fine but i want set the dynamic value like this

Comment: public function deleteImage($imageName = null){
        $myarray = array_filter(getCarImages(), function ($v) {
            return $v['image'] != $imageName;
        });

Comment: but its giving me this error Message: Undefined variable: imageName

Answer (score 1):

You can trans the images as a reference to the function.

```
public function deleteImage(&$images){
    foreach ($images as $k => $array){
        //var_dump($array).'<br>';
        $index = array_search('w85YrKChBGTZ9fQS.jpg',$array);
        if($index !== FALSE){
            var_dump($index).'<br>';
            unset($images[$k]);
        }else{
            echo '<br>else here';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @KrisRoofe Are we allowed to overtly ask for upvotes.  I should be doing that on all of my best answers.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47725480/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa Yeah, you're right. I take your advise.